# Using pyplot.close() crashes the flask app

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, flask

I'm making a web app with Flask which displays different pyplot charts on a single webpage. Following is the code which I'm using to create different plots and then return them as a base64 encoded png image.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import base64


def simple_plot():
    img = io.BytesIO()
    np.random.seed(196801)
    x = np.random.rand(50)
    y = np.random.rand(50)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    lp = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    plt.close()
    return lp

def scatter_plot():
    img = io.BytesIO()
    np.random.seed(19680801)
    x = np.random.rand(30)
    y = np.random.rand(30)
    colors = np.random.rand(30)
    area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(30)) ** 2
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    sp = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    plt.close()
    return sp


def linear_reg_plot():
    data = pd.read_csv("data/clean_df.csv")
    lm = LinearRegression()
    img = io.BytesIO()
    X = data[['highway-mpg']]
    Y = data['price']
    lm.fit(X, Y)
    predict = np.around(np.array(lm.predict(X)))
    intercept = lm.intercept_
    slope = lm.coef_
    plt.plot(X, predict)
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    plot = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    plt.close()
    x = data['highway-mpg'].values.tolist()
    y = data['price'].values.tolist()
    result = {
        'X': x[:50],
        'Y': y[:50],
        'Predicted': predict[:50],
        'intercept': intercept,
        'slope': slope,
        'msqe': mean_squared_error(y, predict),
        'r2': lm.score(X, predict),
        'chart': plot
    }
    return result
```

If I don't use the plt.close() it causes all of the graphs to become same (same sort of data plotted on all of them). But after using he `plt.close()` it displays the correct plots but now I am facing this error which is causing the flask app to crash as well as there's a message box saying that Python is crashed.
Following the error shown by the debugger:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2018 14:55:04] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x000000644962F0F0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x0000006449638048>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x00000064495AAA20>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x00000064495D5C50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x00000064495B61D0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x0000006448E629E8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x0000006448EC8940>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x0000006448E69160>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

The below picture is shows the plots being displayed as well as the error:
[Python crash error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF78H.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right before the line

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

add

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

Currently, matplotlib is accessing the "tkagg" backend that connects to the GUI event loop and that causes unexpected behaviour. The plain "agg" backend does not connect to the GUI at all.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out.

Comment: Cool, glad to know :-)

Comment: Thanks, good answer. This was also the solution for:
`Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7f842d9e19e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3507, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
Aborted (core dumped)`